# How to change Xcode settings from Standard Architectures to Universal?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting the `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error when I try to compile my iOS app, and I'm trying to follow the solution [here](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/fix-for-undefined-symbols-when-building-in-xcode-6/16780). When I expand the options for architectures, I see this:

[image]

How do I "Change it from "Standard Architectures" to "Universal"" as the solution states? I tried replacing `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` with `$(ARCHS_UNIVERSAL)`, but this didn't work.